# Postgres to_tsquery - strange results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am very confused about the usage of to_tsquery and the regconfig parameter.

PostgreSQL 9.0.2 on Windows is used.

```
SELECT name_with_city 
FROM company 
WHERE name_with_city @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'aires|aires:*')

0 rows retrieved.
```

..which is the correct result,
but:

```
SELECT name_with_city 
FROM company 
WHERE name_with_city @@ to_tsquery('english', 'aires|aires:*')

"Bel-Air Express Paris"
"Med-Air Miami"
"APS Air Parts Tel Aviv"
"Air Malta Luga"
"Air Nauru Melbourne"
...
542 rows retrieved.
```

seems to search for "air" instead of "aires".. as i understood that is due the 'english' dictionary..

But using 'simple' doesn't always work either.

```
SELECT name_with_city 
FROM company 
WHERE name_with_city @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'harms|harms:*')

0 rows retrieved.
```

which is wrong, but

```
SELECT name_with_city 
FROM company 
WHERE name_with_city ILIKE 'harms%'

"Harms & Wende Hamburg"
1 rows retrieved.
```

..is correct.

What query i have to use instead? 
As i understood, i can use to_tsquery to find partial words in a text column, e.g.: searching for "tech*" would give out "Lufthansa Technik" and "Technical Aero" but not "Airtech".

Comment: try to look on result ts_debug http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-debugging.html

Answer (score 3):

If the default tsearch configuration (see `get_current_ts_config()`) is **english** , then

```
name_with_city @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'harms|harms:*')
```

is equivalent to:

```
to_tsvector('english', name_with_city) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'harms|harms:*');
```

which indeed is not what you want to avoid english stemming, you'd rather want:

```
to_tsvector('simple', name_with_city) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'harms|harms:*');
```

With the sample string 'Harms & Wende Hamburg', if `simple` configuration is used for both the `tsvector` and the `tsquery`, the sample query matches:

```
select 1 WHERE to_tsvector('simple','Harms & Wende Hamburg') 
    @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'harms|harms:*');
=> 1
```

Conclusion: either issue `SET default_text_search_config='simple'` or use explicitly the `to_tsvector('simple', column_name)` form in the TS queries instead of just `column_name`.